# How to iterate XML data using XSL without hardcoding element names?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

We're transforming this xml data into pipe-delimited format using XSL...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<LIBRARY> 
   <BOOK> 
        <TITLE>Professional JINI</TITLE> 
        <AUTHOR>Sing Li</AUTHOR>
        <PUBLISHER>Wrox Publications</PUBLISHER>
   </BOOK> 
</LIBRARY>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <!-- New line character variable -->
    <xsl:variable name="newline">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">         
        <xsl:for-each select="LIBRARY/BOOK">
            <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>|<xsl:value-of select="AUTHOR"/>|<xsl:value-of select="PUBLISHER"/>   
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>       
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output...

```
Professional JINI|Sing Li|Wrox Publications
```

Is there a way to get the values of TITLE, AUTHOR, etc..from without hard coding the element names in xsl:value-of? We want this XSL to be generic so that if we add more book attributes later the style sheet will automatically capture those new fields.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an XSLT 1.0 complete solution that is probably among the simplest (no `xsl:for-each`, push style) shortest possible**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="BOOK">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="BOOK/*">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">|</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<LIBRARY>
   <BOOK>
        <TITLE>Professional JINI</TITLE>
        <AUTHOR>Sing Li</AUTHOR>
        <PUBLISHER>Wrox Publications</PUBLISHER>
   </BOOK>
   <BOOK>
        <TITLE>XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference</TITLE>
        <AUTHOR>Michael Kay</AUTHOR>
        <PUBLISHER>Wrox Publications</PUBLISHER>
   </BOOK>
</LIBRARY>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Professional JINI|Sing Li|Wrox Publications
XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference|Michael Kay|Wrox Publications
```

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="BOOK">
  <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">
   <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="*" separator="|"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean a concatenation of all subelements with | separating them?

```
<xsl:for-each select="node()>|<xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I want the output to be the same, but I don't want to hard-code the element names in xsl:value-of, I want to be more generic to support any number of book elements.

Comment: I tried than, and the correct values do get extracted, but the output format is messed up, it's not on a single line; it's actually similar to the source Xml; looks like the white space is getting pulled in from the source; how can I prevent that?

Comment: I figured it out, <xsl:for-each select="*"><xsl:value-of select="."/>|</xsl:for-each>, thx

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 you can write `<xsl:value-of select="*" separator="|"/>`

Comment: @RaffiM: The code in your comment above generates an `|` at the very end of each line -- you don't want this.